# Getting error while uploading some selected images

Tags: php, file-upload

I have the following php code for uploading images on my website.

//codes

```
global $objDB;

global $path_to_image_directory ; 

global $path_to_thumbs_directory ;

$final_width_of_image = 500;  

$path_to_image_directory =  'uploads/fullsized/';  

$path_to_thumbs_directory = 'uploads/thumbs/'; 

$imagetitle="";

$mysqli = $objDB->connection;


if(isset($_FILES['uploaded']['name']))
{

 if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(gif)|(png)$/', $_FILES['uploaded']['name'])) {



    $filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name']; 

    $source = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name']; 

    $target = $path_to_image_directory . $filename;  

    move_uploaded_file($source, $target);  

    createThumbnail($filename);   


    $sql="INSERT INTO gallery(image)VALUES('$filename')";
    $result=$objDB->query($sql);

     if($result==1)
    {
    header("location:gallery.php?s_msg=Image added To gallery");
    }
    else
    {
      header("location:gallery.php?f_msg=Unable to Add Image");
    }       
}


else
    {
      header("location:gallery.php?f_msg=Unable to Add Image");
    }   
}

else
    {
      header("location:gallery.php?f_msg=Unable to Add Image");
    }       



function createThumbnail($filename) {  

    $path_to_image_directory="";

$path_to_thumbs_directory="";

$final_width_of_image="";

$path_to_image_directory =  'uploads/fullsized/';  

    $path_to_thumbs_directory = 'uploads/thumbs/';

$final_width_of_image = 400; 

if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {  
   $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename);   
} else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {  
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);  
} else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {  
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);  
}  



$ox = imagesx($im);  

$oy = imagesy($im);  



$nx = $final_width_of_image;  
$ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));  

$nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);  

imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);  

if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {  
  if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {  
       die("There was a problem. Please try again!");  
  }   
   }  

imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename);  

}
```

Everything was working fine till yesterday, when user tried to upload an image of size about 1MB

and is throwing error :

```
Premature end of JPEG file in db_gallery.php on line 64

fullsized/the_amazing_spider_man_2_movie-2048x1536.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file.
```

The image is uploaded to server but thumbnail is not created, Pls Help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to upload an "gif" or "png" image and check does it throws the same error !